# Pycharm produces different results if debugging with breakpoints

Tags: django, debugging, django-forms, pycharm, breakpoints

I'm using pycharm to debug the django development server for analysing a form instantiation where I'm using forms class inheritance.

If I run my application without stepping into any breakpoints (temporarily disabling all) then everything works as it should.

If I do stop at some breakpoint then the instantiated form produces different results.

In particular I have two multiple choices fields, and sometimes only one or both are not bound to the initial value.

I can see from the debugger that the part of the code that set `field['field_name'].initial = value` is executed, nonetheless randomly I get `field['field_name'].initial == None`.

My `watches` panel is empty so there is no risk that I did modify any values by accident.

This is very weird for me! Why would a code execution change depending if I step or not into some breakpoints?

What might cause this odd behaviour?

**EDIT:**

After a bit more of inspection I limited the error to this block:

```
class MyForm(BaseForm):
    period = forms.ChoiceField() 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['period'].choices = self.get_choices()
```

The method `get_choices` return a dynamically computed list of choices, but even changing this with a static list doesn't change the result.

In fact whenever I perform an update and so I instantiate the `MyForm` with `data` and `instance` arguments the following happens:

- If while debugging I **do not** step in the `self.fields['period'].choices = self.get_choices()`  then everything works fine
- If **I do step** in that line then the form does not validate, "Select a valid choice. **XX** is not one of the available choices."

**EDIT 2:**
In general this seems to happen anytime I step on a line that modifies an attribute of a field, that is, for example:

```
self.fields['period'].choices = self.get_choices()  
self.fields['thingy'].initial = 'hello'
```

I'm so clueless..either pycharm is bugged or Django have some weird observer pattern that change a value B if the value A was accessed, even tough this seems unlikely..

Comment: how do you run the debug? and the server? are the python interpreter, virtualenv and environment vars the same in both cases?

Comment: I do not change anything in the configuration, in one case I just click on the 'disable all breakpoints' and everything works. By simply enabling the breakpoints creates the problem as described

Comment: any updates about this problem? Have the same issue..

Comment: In my case I think one of the possible reasons could be related to having everything in debug mode running twice. So most probably I inspect the first or the second request incoming. That's another mystery by itself that I couldn't solve yet. See my question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/51131988/1191416